# Kotlin Exception not caught?

Tags: android, kotlin, asynchronous

I'm wondering why with the following code the exception doesn't get caught:

```kotlin
private inline fun <reified T : Any> parseResponse(
        httpConnection: HttpURLConnection,
        noinline callback: ResponseBlock<T>?
    ) {
        with(httpConnection) {
            var error: Throwable? = null
            val model = try {
                if (this.responseCode in 200..299) {
                    jacksonObjectMapper().readValue(
                        this.inputStream.bufferedReader().readText(),
                        T::class.java
                    )
                } else {
                    null
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                error = e
                null
            }

            if (model == null && error == null) {
                error = try {
                    if (this.responseCode !in 200..299) {
                        val errorResponse = this.errorStream.bufferedReader().readText()
                        Throwable(errorResponse)
                    } else {
                        null
                    }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e
                }
            }
            error?.let {
                Log.e(this::class.simpleName, it.message, it)
            }
            callback?.invoke(this.responseCode, model, error)
            this.disconnect()
        }
    }
```

The function gets called like this:

```kotlin
private inline fun <reified T : Any> get(
        pathComponents: Array<String>,
        noinline callback: ResponseBlock<T>?,
        queryParameters: Map<String, Any>? = null
    ) {
        thread(start = true) {
            val urlRequest = createUrlRequest(HttpMethod.GET, pathComponents, queryParameters)
            parseResponse(urlRequest, callback)
        }
    }
```

And still I get this exception which causes the app to crash:

```
E/HttpURLConnectionImpl: Failed to connect to /10.0.2.2:8080
    java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /10.0.2.2:8080
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:147)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:411)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:542)
        at io.openremote.app.network.ApiManager$getAppConfig$$inlined$get$1.invoke(ApiManager.kt:148)
        at io.openremote.app.network.ApiManager$getAppConfig$$inlined$get$1.invoke(ApiManager.kt:14)
        at kotlin.concurrent.ThreadsKt$thread$thread$1.run(Thread.kt:30)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
    Process: io.openremote.app, PID: 3901
    java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /10.0.2.2:8080
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:147)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:411)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:542)
        at io.openremote.app.network.ApiManager$getAppConfig$$inlined$get$1.invoke(ApiManager.kt:148)
        at io.openremote.app.network.ApiManager$getAppConfig$$inlined$get$1.invoke(ApiManager.kt:14)
        at kotlin.concurrent.ThreadsKt$thread$thread$1.run(Thread.kt:30)
```

I would say the try/catch blocks would catch the exception, but alas...

What causes the exception not being caught? I would say threading doesn't matter because I use try/catch blocks to handle exceptions in the thread.

### Update

After Laalto's answer, I've updated the code to look like this (for those who are interested):

```kotlin
private inline fun <reified T : Any> parseResponse(
        httpConnection: HttpURLConnection,
        noinline callback: ResponseBlock<T>?
    ) {
        with(httpConnection) {
            val parsedResult = try {
                if (this.responseCode in 200..299) {
                    Triple(
                        this.responseCode, jacksonObjectMapper().readValue(
                            this.inputStream.bufferedReader().readText(),
                            T::class.java
                        ), null
                    )
                } else {
                    val errorResponse = this.errorStream.bufferedReader().readText()
                    Triple(this.responseCode, null, Throwable(errorResponse))
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Triple(0, null, e)
            }

            parsedResult.third?.let {
                Log.e(this::class.simpleName, it.message, it)
            }
            callback?.invoke(parsedResult.first, parsedResult.second, parsedResult.third)
            this.disconnect()
        }
    }
```

Comment: At the end you have access to `responseCode` without a try-catch: `callback?.invoke(this.responseCode, model, error)`

Comment: You're right Laalto. If you added it as an answer, I'll accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacktrace shows an exception trying to call `getResponseCode()`. There's one access to `responseCode` without a `try`-`catch` block at the end:

```
callback?.invoke(this.responseCode, model, error)
```

Earlier catch blocks work just fine but the code goes on to execute this part that then throws an exception.

As in your updated question, you have already restructured the code around this issue.